# Swing and Spring

Tags: java, spring, swing, model-view-controller

I'm using spring to create a `MVC desktop application`.

At the main method, I create a `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

When the controller of the `MainForm` is created, it shows the main form view (JFrame).

I set the `MainFormView` to `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`.

```
// when the MainFormController is created, it shows the MainForm JFrame.
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("...");
try {
   // WAIT FOR MAINFORM CLOSE! How?
} finally {
   ctx.close();       
}
```

My question is:

I need to close the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` ? If yes, how can I do this, wait for the `MainForm` close and than close the application context?

Comment: You don't need to close. Why the question arises? Any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply register shutdown hooks, and it will shutdown nicely on exit.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("...");
ctx.registerShutdownHook();
```

And then not have any ctx.close() directly.